# How to print a word from a string without using any inbuilt method

Tags: java

Suppose there is a string.

> My name is Aditya Kumar Singh.

So how could I print `"Kumar"` without using any inbuilt methods.

*Hint: you can use toCharArray(), charAt(), length methods*

Comment: if you can´t use any inbuild method it´s impossible.

Comment: If you can't use any Java methods you have to do it with Assembler

Comment: Why rebuild the wheel?

Comment: Not at all, because even `System.out.println("Kumar");` **IS** an inbuilt message. Technically, even the main method you are using to do something is such a method. You are asking for the impossible. Or perhaps, more likely, you should clear up what you mean by "inbuilt".

Comment: Printing will require use of in-built methods.

Comment: What if the string is different? Should your program print Kumar if it is a word in the string, or the fifth word, or the first word that beings with a (capital) K?

Comment: Just guessing, did you mean no methods in `String` except `length()` and `charAt()`?

Comment: You can use toCharArray(), charAt() and length methods. Now tell me is it possible or not.

Comment: Assuming Ole is right about the restriction, on what basis should the program pick out "Kumar"? 19th - 23rd chars? 5th word? What?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now we understand the restrictions better. I still don’t understand the requirement, as @slim’s questions also show. And there’s one more thing: since we are not writing your code for you (you wouldn’t want that), you should show us what you have tried and how it failed, so we can understand better what challenges you in order for us to guide you better.

Answer (score 0):

If **not** inbuilt methods of Java, how about [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) ?

```
String array[] = StringUtils.split("My name is Aditya Kumar Singh.", " ");
String result = array[4];
```

Comment: Technically, StringUtils also just uses inbuilt messages (instead of, for example, bytecode manipulation). But obviously, the question makes no sense at all ;-)

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz haha, I know. This answer is just a joke, lame, huh :-) OP is asking for the impossible.

Answer (score 0):

what about :

```
String str = "My name is Aditya Kumar Singh.";
System.out.print(str.split(" ")[4]);
```